# require inside new Function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm debugging a code that one of the past workers in my company wrote in order to do a cosmetic update and can't understand something.

The code compiles a string to a function using `new Function(object)` when object is my input.
I'm trying to read a file inside my input like this - `require("fs").readFileSync("myfile.txt")` but the function throw an exception that `require is not defined`.

How can I access `require` inside new Function, or otherwise- how can I read a file content in a different way inside `new Function`?

Thanks

Comment: Do not do that.

Comment: Where is this code running?  `require()` will be defined in node.js, but will not be defined in Javascript that runs in the browser.  It is also generally a bad practice to be using `new Function()` to dynamically write new code.  There are weird exceptions where one might do that, but most of the time a pre-compiled function that you pass arguments to is the desired way to code.

Comment: Can you expand on why you need to use `new Function()`? `eval` and `new Function()` are discouraged for security and performance, and I wouldn't want you to use `new Function()` unless you have to.

Answer (score 3):

If for whatever reason you need to use `new Function()` you can pass in a reference to `fs` or anything else with something like:

```
const fs = require('fs')
let someFn = new Function('fs', "let text = fs.readFileSync('test.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'}); console.log(text)")
someFn(fs)
```

You can also pass in `require` the same way, but that seems even uglier.

The problem is that when you create a function with `new Function()`, your function operates in Node's global scope. But in Node there are some names that are added to all modules that might appear global, but are not actually on the global object. These include `__dirname`, `__filename`, and `require`. The result is that functions created with `new Function()` can't access them directly.

Here's a simpler example. The first `console.log` works, but the one second throws a ReferenceError:

```
console.log(__dirname)
let someF = new Function("console.log(__dirname)")
someF()
```

For more see: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html

Comment: @jfriend00 agreed on the first point. On the second, you should try this in node: let `let someFn = new Function("let fs = require('fs')"); someFn()`

Comment: @jfriend00: *"why isn't require() defined? "* `new Function`s are created in global scope, and I assume that `require` is passed somehow magically to the module scope? But I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes @FelixKling. It's documented here: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html -- I'll add an edit.

Comment: *"This variable may appear to be global but is not. See require()."* lol

Comment: @FelixKling - Ah, I see.

Comment: I suggest passing in an input or scope object and assigning values you wish to access inside of it. E.g. `someF({ app, require, resolve, server, etc })`